# How to show Miniaturize button in fullscreen NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, nswindow, minimize

I have an `NSWindow` with a "Primary Window" Fullscreen behavior.
As always in fullscreen mode if mouse hovers on the top of the screen the Titlebar appears. But only "Close" and "Fullscreen" buttons are presented. And there is a grey circle on the "Miniaturise" button place.
How to make "Miniaturise" button visible and enabled?

I've tried StyleMasks - doesn't working.

`[[[self window] standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton] setHidden:NO]`   - doesn't work

`[[[self window] standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton] setEnabled:YES];` - nope

this doesn't work also:

```
NSButton *button = [[self window] standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton];
NSButtonCell *buttonCell = [button cell];
[buttonCell setEnabled:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong?

### **Update/conclusion:**

Looks like there is no solution. It's just windows managing logic of MacOS.
So, don't bother.